# ByteString.Lazy.Char8 (Not enough space)

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, bytestring

This code gives `<stdin>: hGetBufSome: resource exhausted (Not enough space)` error as soon as it's executed.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B8
main = do
    (l:_) <- B8.lines `fmap` B8.getContents
    B8.putStrLn l
```

I'm just trying to get the first line. So because of lazy loading it wouldn't try to get others right? I can't figure out how to avoid this error.

Comment: What version of GHC and OS are you running on?

Comment: and is your GHC 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Windows 7 x64, GCH 64 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with lazy bytestrings on 64-bit Windows 7, e.g.

- [this pandoc patch (July 2013)](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/aab4c47da5c25c9dc284da698b28d351ec033e15)
- [a Haskell-Cafe posting (July 2013)](https://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-July/109022.html)
- [an lpaste posting (March 2013)](http://lpaste.net/83606)

Since the reports are all from over a year ago, I would try using GHC 7.8.3 (for example, from the Haskell Platform 2014.2.0.0) if you are not already using that version.

Comment: Should I switch to 32bit version?

Comment: Oh ****, I've just spent few hours trying to figure it out assuming that it was my fault, since I'm the newbie

Comment: Yeah - I would try that. Are you using the Haskell Platform?

Comment: Yes, HaskellPlatform-2014.2.0.0-x86_64

Answer (score 1):

Here's the bug report against GHC on this issue: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11009#ticket

I guess the solution for now is to not use getContents on lazy bytestrings (switch to strict or just read incrementally).